# What is a limit to the size of a single document CouchDb

Tags: couchdb

I have a problem with document storage complex data structure, which may vary. Document need to store and retrieve whole. Need to provide a document search fields. 
I began to store documents in MongoBb, but the size of the document there is limited to 16 MB, which is not enough for me. 
What is the maximum size of a single document allows CouchDb?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CouchDB maximum document size is set via the max_document_size parameter in the .ini file for your instance. The defaults

```
max_document_size = 4294967296 ; 4 GB
max_attachment_chunk_size = 4294967296 ; 4GB
```

mean that for both documents and attachments the default maximum size is 4 GB. I am uncertain if you can raise it above that value.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/couchdb.html?highlight=max_document_size
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Configurationfile_couch.ini

Comment: Thanks John! This size would be enough for me.

Comment: CouchDB 4.0 (currently unreleased) will have a hard limit of 8MB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60341333

Comment: @DharmaTurtle Any idea why they impose this limit? Will there be any way to change it?

Comment: @Arek CouchDB 4.0's future is... questionable. https://lists.apache.org/thread/9gby4nr209qc4dzf2hh6xqb0cn1439b7