# Will CouchDB accept the largest possible file that could reside in a FAT32 fs?

Tags: couchdb, fat32, couchdb-python

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24222187/4240261

Will I be able to upload as an attachment the largest possible file (¿ ~4GB) that could fit in the FAT32 limit to my CouchDB database, or for such files I will have to use, for example, a single-node CephFS? Also, what overheads do count here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a limit to the size of a single document CouchDb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221647/what-is-a-limit-to-the-size-of-a-single-document-couchdb)

Comment: @AlexisCôté Well, not really, as here it is about not only maximum size of a fat32 file and the couchdb file size limit, but also about the size of metadata in both cases, the HTTP and metadata overhead limit being counted, etc. It is quite a complex question, and one has to understand quite much about the way it works on a very low level, and possibly analyse it byte after byte or conduct experiments. I have not enough knowledge or experience to conduct such tests in a reasonable time, and I'm considering storing those files in an ordinary filesystem, naming them after their checksums.

Comment: As you may know, attachments will heavily decrease the performances of CouchDB. Although this feature exists in CouchDB, it's always a better idea to store the files on an external storing system.

Comment: @AlexisCôté Yeah. On some old Athlon X4 with 4GB RAM it would start lagging after just a few such files, I guess, right?

Comment: I can't tell you exactly if it will or not. I suggest that you change or update your questions. As mentioned in my duplicate flag, we know that you will be able to store files of 4gb. The maximum for documents is ~4gb and this limits does not apply to attachment. Either way, I'm gonna let someone with a better understanding of the question answer you. You might wanna take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961191/scalable-image-storage

Comment: @AlexisCôté Looks like a great lecture, thanks :) And as I probably won't come back to CouchDB with that and nobody else should need such an answer, I think this question could be closed (and even if, these comments should be the answer for them), I don't know how though.